# Custom UIImageView added to UItableview cell doesnot shift on on x-axis?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to give some margin on x-axis for a imageView that is set inside a tableView cell. But the imageView does not move. And I also tried same for a label. It does shift to the value I gave.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
//  cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 22)
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as UITableViewCell
//  cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named: self.cellImgs[indexPath.row])
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.cellTxtArrs[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.400, blue: 0.404, alpha: 1.00)
    cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


//  var videoImgView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 20, 30.0))
//  let videoImage = UIImage(named: "accounts")
//  videoImgView = UIImageView(image: videoImage)
//  cell.contentView.addSubview(videoImgView)

    var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 30.0))
    newLabel.text = "hello all"
    newLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(newLabel)

    return cell
}
```

I have created a table view as

```
var tblView : UITableView = UITableView()
tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 168, 320-50 , 448)
tblView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
tblView.scrollEnabled = false
tblView.rowHeight = 39
self.addSubview(tblView)
tblView.delegate = self
tblView.dataSource = self
tblView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Comment: Where's your imageview code ? and Are you using autolayout??

Comment: the commented line is the image view code.  no i am not using

Comment: Please try to see my code

Answer (score 0):

1) your code will `cell.contentView.addSubview` everytime that `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  is called. You are not reusing cell properly .

2) Subclass UITableViewCell and add your "logic View code" inside there (right place to do it)

3) look at this: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html

Comment: can i create a custom cell without  storyboards?

Comment: Sure. I hate storyboard, I always use XIB files.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one i hope it helps you.

```
    videoImgView = UIImageView(image: videoImage)
    videoImgView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 20, 30.0)
   cell.contentView.addSubview(videoImgView)
```